# Is there a way to append tables within a do.call() when using dplyr verbs within a database?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, lapply, dbplyr

Say there's a list of dataframes that is generated following a `lapply` call on some vector and the aim is to append the list of dataframes to one another to form a single dataframe. In R, one approach is `do.call(rbind, data.ls)`, where `data.ls` is a list object composed of a list of dataframes. This approach also works with `dplyr`'s `bind_rows` in the exact same way but it does NOT work with the SQL's eponymous `union_all` when one is binding more than two dataframes. In most cases that's fine but what does one do when working in a database enviornment and one's data is too heavy to `collect` before the end of the `lapply` call (and there are more than two dataframes to append)? This phenomena is not unique to `dbplyr` either. The authors of the `sparklyr` package recognized the limitations of `union_all` and implemented a `sparklyr` verb that accomplished what `rbind`/`bind_rows` does in a local environment -`sdf_bind_rows`. I'm curious if there's an analogous `dplyr`/`dbplyr` verb to accomplish or some other approach that can accomplish this that still relies on the results of the `lapply` call -i.e. the list of dataframes.

From `sparklyr` documentation:

> **Description**
>
> sdf_bind_rows() and sdf_bind_cols() are implementation of the common
>   pattern of do.call(rbind, sdfs) or do.call(cbind, sdfs) for binding
>   many Spark DataFrames into one.

Comment: If `x` is your list of data frames, something like `purrr::reduce(x, union_all)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following for `rbind`:

```r
dbplyr_union_all <- function(...){
  tbl_list <- list(...)
  db_con <- list[[1]]$src$con # extract database connection

  # construct query that defines unioned table
  query_text = sapply(tbl_list, dbplyr::sql_render)
  sql_query = paste0(query_text, collapse = "\nUNION ALL\n")

  sql_query <- dbplyr::build_sql(sql_query, con = db_con)
  return(dplyr::tbl(db_con, dbplyr::sql(sql_query)))
}
```